# Surrogate database key and data duplication

Tags: database, database-design

I was thinking about this problem. In database design most of the times surrogate keys are used, but how to prevent data duplication and inconsistent data? I mean one could have a customer table made of customer_id, name, surname. What would prevent me of inserting the same customer twice with a different customer_id? Sure I could add a unique index to name and surname, but if one does so than what's the purpose of the surrogate primary key?

Comment: The surrogate key makes it **possible** to have two customers with the same name/surname - also: joining on a **single column** (the surrogate key) is much easier than having to specify multiple keys for every join from a child table to the parent

Comment: Yes, but how to solve the duplicated customer problem ???

Comment: Either you put a unique constraint on (first name, last name) - but then you're making it **impossible** to have two customers of the same name - which is totally possible! Or you need to handle this in your application some way - how do you **know** whether a customer is a duplicate? Based on what criteria???

Comment: With only name and surname, it's impossible to define/declare a unique constraint. If you have other values for example email, SSN, etc. that (teorically) are unique, you could add a unique constraint to that value.

Comment: But if one is forced to use a unique constraint on the data, couldn't one use that data as a natural composed key ? What would be the advantage of the surrogate key ? Joins maybe ?

Comment: I wouldn't use that data, because a customer could change his name/surname :)

Comment: Perfect natural key would be [person's DNA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AC006457.4) :-)

Comment: Alfio, in principle there is nothing wrong with using natural keys and composite keys. They are in fact essential to good database design. It's just that your example isn't very helpful because it seems extremely unlikely that name and surname would ever be a sensible choice of natural key for customers.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a business question, not a technical one.

"How do I know whether two people with the same name are the same person or not?"

Well typically customers are not identified by a name alone, there is also one of:

1. An account number
2. An email address
3. A postal address
4. A credit card number
5. A passport number
6. A date of birth

... etc.

The name is simply not a uniquely identifying characteristic, it's just an attribute of a customer that is probably non-unique, so you need something else to help identify them. Within the database this is the primary key of the customer table, but for business purposes it could be any number of attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a natural key, you cannot *replace* it with a surrogate key. You can only *add* the surrogate without removing the natural. This has pros and cons, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info).

Unfortunately, there is no good natural key in the case you described, since two different human beings can easily have the same combination of first and last name. Therefore, you'll have to come-up with some additional attributes that represent a better criteria for judging whether two people are "identical" or not, and then create the corresponding natural key. Discovering such criteria is part of the requirement gathering and therefore impossible for me to do without knowing more about your domain.

If you are unable to identify such natural key, then you can just leave `customer_id` alone. That means you made a decision to make it acceptable for two people to be identical in every aspect (except in their `customer_id`) and still be considered "different". Arguably, such `customer_id` may no longer be called "surrogate", since its value now has a meaning in your data model, is potentially visible in the UI etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you have said is perfectly logical and correct. Surrogate keys are **not** any kind of substitute for a *natural key* (AKA *business key* or *domain key*, i.e. the set of attributes used to identify information in the database and relate it to the real world things the database is supposed to model). If you care about data integrity then natural keys are essential, whereas surrogates by definition are optional and supplemental. Add surrogate keys only when and where you find they have a useful benefit.

Answer (score 0):

**The *only* purpose of the id** (or "surrogate key" as you call it) is to **uniquely identify a record.**

First, say you will use name as a key. What will you do if:

- the customer changes its name (in some countries women change their surname to their husbands');
- you make a typo in customers name and have to correct it afterwards?

Then you are in a big trouble, because despite of the fact that you *can* change it,

#### **id should never be changed!**

Otherwise, you can make a big mess not only in your database, consistency along backups, logs etc, but also in all the external sources refering to it.

Second, how do you know you won't get  **two customers with the same name?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop people from describing the world wrongly in the database. You can only stop them from describing the world wrongly in the database if the way they described it *can't ever happen*.

When there is no previous "natural" identifying property used in the business outside the database being stored in the database then we have to pick a "surrogate" distinguishing identifier after the system starts. (Some people wouldn't use "natural" for such an identifier picked after the system starts even though it is used in the business outside the database. And some people wouldn't use "surrogate" for such a distinguishing identifier used in the business system outside the database.)